# MySQL - Error 1045, access denied

Tags: mysql, mamp

**EDIT**: Fixed it by creating `'fakaff'@'localhost'`.

---

First time using MySQL, using latest MAMP installation. Following the tutorial, I started by creating a database:

```
CREATE publications; USE publications;
```

Next, I created a user. I tried both variations but both give me `ERROR 1045`:

```
GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'fakaff' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

and

```
GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'fakaff@localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345'; 
//edit: clearly I screwed up the syntax here so it didn't work.
```

When I try to log in and enter my password, I get this message:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqp -u fakaff -p
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fakaff'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

---

Any idea what's causing the error? I've not played with any settings or entered any commands other than the ones I listed.

Comment: Have you tried [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html)?

Comment: @eggyal Just tried it, still no luck. It returned `0 rows affected` when I entered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'flush privileges'. It's either that, or you haven't allowed remote access, but since this is local, that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Creating `'fakaff'@'localhost'` fixed it. So I'm guessing the latter was the problem and it was treating the first account as a remote user?

Comment: Ah i think what you did was create a 'fakaff@localhost' user.